# MBProgressHUD and UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, mbprogresshud, hud

I am displaying a HUD while populating the TableView, but it seems to be showing behind the TableView (tableview separator breaking the hud).

[image]

Here's the code in the TableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
hud.labelText = @"Loading";

// Populate the table
[self getTableData];

self.tableView.rowHeight = 90;
}
```

It's doing this only with TableViews.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue here is that you are adding the HUD when the view loads, which is likely before your tableView has been displayed, so the tableView is created and appears to cover the HUD. Move that code into viewDidAppear and your problem will go away:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
    hud.labelText = @"Loading";
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `self.navigationController.view` instead of `self.view` if you want to implement in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 10):

Include this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

You can use **layer.zPosition** to order the visibility of your objects/views.

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
hud.labelText = @"Loading";
hud.layer.zPosition = 2;
self.tableView.layer.zPosition = 1;
```

The higher zPosition value, more priority in display.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! and the demo of `MBProgressHUD` use this too

Answer (score 0):

```
Even in ViewDidLoad also we can handle it like this::   
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];     
   MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
  hud.labelText = @"Loading..";
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
   [self contactsFromAddressBook];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
       [self.tableView reloadData];

     });
  });
```

}