# ios - how do I set layers programmatically?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

.

Hello,

In Interface builder it really easy to set the order of items, as in the layers by dragging them one above the other.

I am not being successful to replicate that in code.

What is the line I need to add to have a similar effect?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663526/1388247), there are many useful methods for this exact purpose:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) UIView *superview;
@property(nonatomic,readonly,copy) NSArray *subviews;

- (void)removeFromSuperview;
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (void)exchangeSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index1 withSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index2;

- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view;
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view belowSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview;
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view aboveSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview;

- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view;
- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view;
```

Their names are fairly self explanatory. Of particular interest to you might be insertSubview:AtIndex, insertSubview:belowSubview (or above), as well as the bringSubviewToFront and sendSubviewToBack. These will allow you to build your view without having to add them in any specific order.

Answer (score 0):

Just subview them in reversed order (if you want it on top, subview last). There are also functions to insert subview before or after a reference subview.