# Programatically Hiding Status Bar When Adding New UIWindow?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, statusbar, uiwindow

I'm currently adding a new UIWindow to my app when displaying my own custom alert.

Before adding this UIWindow my app had the status bar hidden, but now it is visible. How can I hide the status bar programatically in this new window. I've tried everything but it doesn't work.

This is how I add my UIWindow:

```
notificationWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1.0, 1.0)];

notificationWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // your color if needed
notificationWindow.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // if needed

// IMPORTANT PART!
notificationWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;

notificationWindow.rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
notificationWindow.hidden = NO; // This is also important!
[notificationWindow addSubview:confettiView];
```

Comment: How do you hide status bar? I have tried "[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];" and everything works ok.

Comment: I tried doing that but the status bar still shows up. When I change the windowLevel to UIWindowStatusBar it disappears, but then the UIAlertView is always on top.

Comment: @iwasrobbed This question was tagged Objective-C, not Swift. Please do not change the meaning or the scope of a *question* just to make it go with your new answer. If you have an answer to this question, you can post an Objective-C version, as requested by OP. Discussed on Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311285/user-adding-off-topic-tag-to-question-to-make-it-inline-with-their-answer

Answer (score 6):

Essentially, since each `UIWindow` is independent of each other, you need to tell each one that you create what your preference is for the status bar.

In order to do this programmatically, you have to create a faux controller with your given preference so that when you unhide the new `UIWindow`, the status bar doesn't show/hide or flash on the screen.

```
class FauxRootController: UIViewController {

    // We effectively need a way of hiding the status bar for this new window
    // so we have to set a faux root controller with this preference
    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

and the implementation would look like:

```
lazy private var overlayWindow: UIWindow = {
    let window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    window.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
    window.rootViewController = FauxRootController()
    return window
}()
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `notificationWindow` has a rootViewController. Therefore implement Custom UIViewController as rootViewController with preferStatusBarHidden method as

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
  return YES;
}
```

instread of using default UIViewController instance `[UIViewController new]`.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2 Answer**

Create a `ViewController` class:

```
class NoStatusBarViewController: UIViewController {    

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {

        return true

    }

}
```

And in your `UIWindow` class:

```
rootViewController = NoStatusBarViewController()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use UIAlertController instead of UIAlertView.

```
notificationWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal;
```