# Inserting Subview Below UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, subview

When I add a subview below a UICollectionView, sometimes the subview shows up above the UICollectionView cells.  Here is the subview insertion code:

```
[self.collectionView insertSubview:self.garmentView atIndex:0];
```

Not sure if I'm not following a best practice or otherwise missing something obvious.  Any assistance appreciated.

** Edit ** It might be worth noting that this only happens in landscape, when the rightmost cell is zoomed in.

Comment: Do you have custom view for each collection cell?

Comment: Each cell has a UIImage and a UILabel.

Comment: When you say below, do you mean outside the collection view? If so, you should use a UIViewController with a collection view as one of the subviews. A UICollectionViewController (like a UITableViewController) doesn't have any other view, other than the collection view, so you can't add subviews that don't become part of the collection view.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I'm using a UICollectionViewController subclass that makes it easier to hook into Core Data, and I'd rather not deviate if I can avoid it.  Please see my edit above in case that helps.  Much appreciated, your idea does make sense.

Comment: Subclassing `UICollectionViewController` makes sense. Your edit could suggest that you need to do more work in the `prepareForReuse` method in your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass.

Answer (score 11):

I think

```
self.garmentView.layer.zPosition = -1
[self.collectionView insertSubview:self.garmentView atIndex:0];
```

will solve your problem. My guess is that it can happen that the collection view cells gets added with a lower index than your garmentView. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631878/how-to-set-iphone-ui-view-z-index) for a more thorough discussion about subview positions.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  The garmentView now appears below the collectionView cell, but clicking on the cell still doesn't work.

Comment: I would try `self.garmentView.userInteractionEnabled = YES` in case it intercepts and blocks the touch events. If the problem persists I would investigate by putting a symbolic breakpoint in `[UIResponder touchesBegan:withEvent:]` and try to track what happens to the touch down event.

Comment: I NSLogged self.garmentView.userInteractionEnabled at the relevant moment and it is YES.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
[self.collectionView addSubview:self.garmentView];
[self.collectionView insertSubview:self.garmentView belowSubview:self.collectionView];
```

Are you using storyboard? What member of class is your controller?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a storyboard.  The controller is a UICollectionViewController.