# How can I make my cells selectable when there is an UIView below the UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, subview

I have a collection view, and added a UIView below it. The cells shows up on top of it, but they aren't selectable. How can I make them selectable again?

What I have tried so far:

UIView has zPosition -1 and my cells have +1
UIView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

I have tried to add the UIView both as view.addSubview and collectionView?.addSubview

collectionView?.insertSubview(UIView, belowSubview: collectionView!)

This guy has the same problem, with no solution provided: [Inserting Subview Below UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353479/inserting-subview-below-uicollectionview/44906665?noredirect=1#comment76790209_44906665)

Edit: I'm using this code to determine what cells are selected

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    //Code here...
}
```

It all works when there is no UIView below. But I want to have a visible "container" for my collectionview content insets, so I created an UIView.
Problem is the above code doesn't get fired at all when clicking on the cells with the UIView below.

Comment: use `view.addSubview` first and then call `view.bringSubview(toFront: collectionView!)`

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Comment: Great.... I have added it is as an answer, please accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because your other view is covering the collection view.

Use `view.addSubview` first and then call `view.bringSubview(toFront: collectionView!)`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do the selection manually at the moment when the view is tapped:

```
func selectItem(at: IndexPath?, animated: Bool, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition)
```

Can you show more in code?

Comment: I do, using this to determine which cell is selected:
        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
         //code here...
    }