# How to get Google Map's 'myLocationEnabled' blue dot always on top

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, uiimageview

This is an example of a UIImageView inside of a GMSMapView. My problem is that Google's blue dot is showing behind the UIImageView...How can I get this blue dot for `myLocationEnabled` to always show on top?

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
    
    NSLog("Did Change Authorization Status")
    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        
        //This uses the location manager
        if locationManager.location != nil {
            currentLatitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
            currentLongitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
        }
        //How do I get this over my UIImageView?
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        
        var TARGET: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLatitude, longitude: currentLongitude)
        var camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition(target: TARGET, zoom: 12, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
        mapView.camera = camera        
    }
}
```

[image]

All of these red circles are One UIImageView, that is inside of the MapView. I want the Current Location to be on top of this UIImageView...but using `mapView.myLocationEnabled = true` is only boolean property and is not a view or a marker...or anything really.. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Any help would be awesome...thanks.

[image: UIImageView inside of GMSMapView]

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631878/how-to-set-iphone-ui-view-z-index.

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: no, I was not able to resolve this

Comment: I am having the same problem, here in 2019 using version 3.0.2 of the Google Maps SDK. Have you ever solved the problem?

Comment: nope, never solved