# Turn on system dark mode from app - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13

I have made my own system of dark mode on my app using `Notifications` and I have a switch that changes between dark mode on and off.

My first question: How do I turn on system dark mode, where the whole phone becomes dark mode as well if it is updated to iOS 13 by flipping the switch.

My second question: How do I check to see if system dark mode is enabled so that I can make it where my dark mode is enabled whenever the iOS system dark mode is enabled?

Comment: First question - not possible.

Comment: Second question - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/appearance_customization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **First question:** Impossible at this moment
- **Second Question:** [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56435721/4950794) of **Tamás Sengel**

---

You should check the `userInterfaceStyle` variable of `UITraitCollection`, same as on tvOS and macOS.

```
switch traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {
case .light: //light mode
case .dark: //dark mode
case .unspecified: //the user interface style is not specified
}
```

You should use the [`traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitenvironment/1623516-traitcollectiondidchange) function of `UIView`/`UIViewController` to detect changes in the interface environment (including changes in the user interface style).

From [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitenvironment/1623516-traitcollectiondidchange):

> The system calls this method when the iOS interface environment changes. Implement this method in view controllers and views, according to your app’s needs, to respond to such changes. For example, you might adjust the layout of the subviews of a view controller when an iPhone is rotated from portrait to landscape orientation. The default implementation of this method is empty.

System default UI elements (such as `UITabBar` or `UISearchBar`) automatically adapt to the new user interface style.

Comment: I am working on a macOS app. Do you know how I can get access to `UITraitCollection` with no `UIKit`?

Answer (score 1):

```
  if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light // or .dark 
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```

with this method you will get the light mode and dark mode, put this code into switch and your view will changes according to dark and light appearance.

Comment: This doesn’t make the whole phone into the specified style. I was asking if there was a way to make a button make your entire phone go into dark mode, as if you had toggled it in settings/control center. And the answer is there is no way as of now.