# How to switch programmatically to dark mode swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-darkmode

How can I make a switch to change programatically to dark or light mode in my iOS app?
I'm using Swift.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701467/turn-on-system-dark-mode-from-app-swift

Comment: It is very much possible. See below.

Comment: ... assuming that you mean "for your app" and not the system setting.

Comment: Full Swift https://betterprogramming.pub/swiftui-app-theme-switch-241a79574b87

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can override the style for single views or view controller using the `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` property. But since the window is also a view, you can set that on your main window to force it into light or dark mode:

```
window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

Comment: FYI: if the view controllers is added into a navigation controller, then it's the later which must have this property set.


`dummyNavigation.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light/.dark`

Comment: window not defined

Comment: To override the entire app, you should be able to use UIWindow().overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyle.light

Comment: @JorgeZapata just to clarify, that won't do anything. (It will apply the override to an unused instance of UIWindow.) Callers should get the window (if available) from the current Scene, which is typically but not always the first Scene in UIApplication's connectedScenes. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

I want to elaborate more on the answer provided by @Frank Schlegel.

To change theme from another view controller in your app (which is what you originally asked for, I think) you could add an observer for a `UserDefaults` value that will trigger the change.

I would add an enum to better represent the theme state

```swift
enum Theme: String {
    case light, dark, system

    // Utility var to pass directly to window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle
    var uiInterfaceStyle: UIUserInterfaceStyle {
        switch self {
        case .light:
            return .light
        case .dark:
            return .dark
        case .system:
            return .unspecified
        }
    }
}
```

In your `SceneDelegate` under your `window` initialisation you have to add this method that is triggered every time `UserDefaults` changes value.

```swift
UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "theme", options: [.new], context: nil)
```

Also, you want to remove that observer when the `SceneDelegate` is deinitialised, add

```swift
deinit {
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "theme", context: nil)
}
```

This will place an observer for that `theme` value in `UserDefaults`.

To handle changes you need to add this method to your `SceneDelegate` class.

```swift
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    guard
        let change = change,
        object != nil,
        keyPath == Defaults.theme.rawValue,
        let themeValue = change[.newKey] as? String,
        let theme = Theme(rawValue: themeValue)?.uiInterfaceStyle
    else { return }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = theme
    }, completion: .none)
}
```

This will be executed every time `theme` value changes in `UserDefaults` and will animate the transition from a theme to another.

Now, to change your theme from other view controllers in your app you just need to change value for `UserDefaults`.

```swift
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Theme.light.rawValue, forKey: "theme")
```

Comment: What if the project does not use the `SceneDelegate` file?

Comment: looks promising, but how to do that if there's just a AppDelegate file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the observation ways, for example, `Defaults` lib, and then add

```swift
window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

to

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {}
```

Comment: works if you need to change it on the fly from the app

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on how this could be used in an app to change to light or dark on the fly?