# How to change just my app between light and dark mode

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-darkmode

I want to have a dark mode option within the settings page of my Xcode swift app. Is it possible to change dark mode just for the app, on all view controllers in the app? I have my dark colors selected in 'Assets.xcassets'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch programmatically to dark mode swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60171262/how-to-switch-programmatically-to-dark-mode-swift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set your app to be only on dark mode, you can simply add

```
overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

to your `viewDidLoad()`, or if you want it to be on the entire app:

- Go to your `Info.plist` file
- Add new key: `UIUserInterfaceStyle` with value `Dark`

Comment: Is it possible to switch all view controllers from a button or something

Comment: I think yes, try adding `overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark` to your button's action

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get it to work using             `window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark` in scene view controller

Comment: Great, happy to help!