# Manually apply dark theme in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, theming

I'm currently creating an Android-app using Xamarin.Forms. I'm trying to implement a settings menu where the user can choose which theme he/she wants to use (system default/light/dark). The system default works fine and dark theme and light theme work as expected.

See images:
[Light theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABQpB.jpg)
[Dark theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQwUK.jpg)

The problem I'm having however is that I seem to be unable to set the app to dark mode manually. What I mean by that is that I'm able to change the colors of e.g. the background and text, but not the color of the background for the DisplayAlert or placeholder text.

I tried using `Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Dark;` but this doesn't seem to do anything (I checked that it was actually set by printing `Application.Current.UserAppTheme` to the console). What am I missing here? How do I set dark theme manually so that dialog boxes look like the one shown in the image above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Finn

Comment: have u created or have you written a style for light and dark theme ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Application.Current.UserAppTheme` only applys for the theme defined with `AppThemeBinding`, but the dialog is build-in we can't customize the color so it would not work in this way .

To manually **enable/disable** the dark theme ,we have to implement on each platform and invoke it in forms with `Dependency service` .

##### Android Solution

1. Change the default theme in `styles.xml` .

```
 <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>  
  </style>
```

2. Define a new `interface` in Forms

```
 public interface IChangeTheme
    {
        void EnableDarkTheme(bool _);
    }
```

3. Implement on Android platform

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Changetheme))]
namespace FormsApp.Droid
{
    class Changetheme : IChangeTheme
    {
        public void EnableDarkTheme(bool _)
        {
            AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = _ ? AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightYes : AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
        }
    }
}
```

4. Invoke in Forms

```
DependencyService.Get<IChangeTheme>().EnableDarkTheme(true);
```

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891471/8187800

##### iOS Solution

Same way with android solution , I haven't test it but it should work ,
refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171521/8187800.