# SwiftUI - How do I check to see if dark mode is enabled?

Tags: swiftui

How do I check to see if dark mode on the device is enabled. I want to check this from within a view and conditionally show or hide a shadow.

I thought I could jus get the colorScheme from the environment but I think I'm missing something.

```swift
struct FloatingAddButton : View {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme 

    @Binding var openAddModal: Bool

    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack() {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {

                    self.openAddModal = true

                }) {

                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color(RetroTheme.shared.appMainTint))
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                        if(self.colorScheme == .light) {
                            .shadow(color: .secondary, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
                        }

                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }

                } // End Button
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: As dfd pointed out below the issue was trying to use an if statement with a modifier. See the updated code in the question.

Comment: Two things, I never saw your comment because you left the "at" (@) sign on your comment. Two years in and I'm still learning too! See my comment on my answer for what I hope you'll do. Between you and both answers this is something **all** can use.

Answer (score 6):

In my code, I have a simple View extension, that makes the code a lot more readable. With it, I can apply modifiers conditionally:

```swift
.conditionalModifier(self.colorScheme == .light, LightShadow())
```

The full implementation is below:

```swift
extension View {
    // If condition is met, apply modifier, otherwise, leave the view untouched
    public func conditionalModifier<T>(_ condition: Bool, _ modifier: T) -> some View where T: ViewModifier {
        Group {
            if condition {
                self.modifier(modifier)
            } else {
                self
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct FloatingAddButton : View {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    @Binding var openAddModal: Bool

    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack() {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: { self.openAddModal = true }) {

                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.red))
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            .conditionalModifier(self.colorScheme == .light, LightShadow())

                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }
                }

            } // End Button

        }
    }
}

struct LightShadow: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.shadow(color: .secondary, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
    }
}
```

If you ever have a case where you want to apply different modifiers for true and false, here's another extension:

```swift
extension View {
    // Apply trueModifier if condition is met, or falseModifier if not.
    public func conditionalModifier<M1, M2>(_ condition: Bool, _ trueModifier: M1, _ falseModifier: M2) -> some View where M1: ViewModifier, M2: ViewModifier {
        Group {
            if condition {
                self.modifier(trueModifier)
            } else {
                self.modifier(falseModifier)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much, **much** more elegant! It took me... a few hours... to get things working in my app that I proposed as a solution. (SwiftUI is new to us all.) As always, at least to me, you are a level or more above most of us UIKit coders (and I barely consider myself one of them). nSweet!

Comment: Thanks @dfd, so kind as always. I have compiled several view extensions aimed at making the code more readable. It's in my blog, as "View Extensions for Better Code Readability". Cheers ;-)

Comment: I check your blog regularly and already have been using one for corner radius. Didn't see this one - but it has me drilling into `some` by your use.

Answer (score 4):

## SwiftUI

With the `\.colorScheme` key of an `Environment` variable:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    var body: some View {
        Text(colorScheme == .dark ? "In dark mode" : "In light mode")
    }
}
```

Also, it automatically updates on the change of the environment color scheme.

---

## UIKit

To check the current, all object those conform to `UITraitEnvironment` protocol, including all `UIView` subclasses and all `UIViewConttroller` subclasses have access to the current style:

```
myUIView.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark
myUIViewController.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark
```

To detect the change of the style, [here is the full detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58017164/5623035)

Answer (score 2):

You *are* using `colorScheme` correctly. But it looks like you have a different issue - placing a modifier inside an `if` statement. I found that, unlike a `View`, modifiers don't work that way.

The answer is to create a custom `ViewModifier`. In your case I'd package everything up into one modifier like this:

```
struct CircleStyle: ViewModifier {
    @Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme:ColorScheme

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {

    if colorScheme == .light {
        return content
            .foregroundColor(Color(RetroTheme.shared.appMainTint))
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .shadow(color: .secondary, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
    } else {
        return content
            .foregroundColor(Color(RetroTheme.shared.appMainTint))
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
Circle()..modifier(CircleStyle())
```

If you need to add more variables from your model, simply pass it into your modifier.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I get a error `Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types`. Thanks for the info about using if statements on modifiers. With that I was able to get it working.

Comment: First, glad I helped. Second, good answer! Too bad it's an edit to your question? Please, post your answer *as* that! There's nothing wrong with that and I'd gladly upvote it. (You can't accept it - I think - but this site is really about *both* the Q and the A. And if I may? Edit the question title to reflect the *real* issue. This helps everyone!)

Comment: Will do, thanks. I'm still kind of new to Stack Overflow so I don't know all of the etiquette

Comment: @radicalappdev did you resolve that error? I'm getting the same, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @dfd for pointing out that I can't use an if statement with a modifier. I updated my code like this for now. This just returns different versions of the circle in light and dark mode.

```swift
if colorScheme == .light {
    Circle()
        .foregroundColor(Color(RetroTheme.shared.appMainTint))
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
        .shadow(color: .secondary, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
} else {
    Circle()
        .foregroundColor(Color(RetroTheme.shared.appMainTint))
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
}
```