# traitCollectionDidChange strange behavior

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
        print("changed")
    }
}
```

The iOS 13 application just goes to background without changing the mode (light/dark) but the "print" function is called. Is it possible to determine the moment when the mode really changed?

Thank You.

Comment: Note it may help to check `UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active` to avoid the problem. Though note then you need to make sure you update your interface properly when the app resumes active if the interface style changes while it's not active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I observed this myself as well.
The user interface toggles as soon as you go to the background, however - it immediately toggles back.
I guess you should simple follow the changes and react as needed.
You can find the current interface style by checking `traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle`.
For instance:
`let isDark = traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark`