# Detect Color type (dark or light)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to detect the Color type (dark or light) in SwiftUI to change the text color accordingly. But there is something wrong, it always giving the value of : 0.41437413557767866 for luminance.

```
struct InfoView: View {
    
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .foregroundColor(isDarkBackground(color: Color.accentColor) ? .darkText : .lightText)
            .background(Color.accentColor)
    }
    
}

private extension InfoView {
    
    func isDarkBackground(color: Color) -> Bool {
        var r, g, b, a: CGFloat
        (r, g, b, a) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        UIColor(color).getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        let luminance = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b
        logger(luminance)
        return  luminance < 0.50

    }
}
```

Also I tried something like:

```
color.cgColor?.components
```

to get the components of the color then calculate the luminance but it's returning nil

What I want to achieve is something like this:

Here the text should be light to be clear:

[image: Here the text should be light to be clear]

And here the text should be dark to be clear:

[image: Here the text should be dark to be clear]

Comment: Not related to your question but if your intent if to get luminance value why don't you use `getWhite` instead of `getRed`?

Comment: @LeoDabus Because all of the resources I found are using getRed, cgColor is nil as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Why don't you add a dynamic color to your text instead of testing the accent color? Have you tried `Color(.label)`? Note that the user may switch from light to dark mode at any time.

Comment: @LeoDabus Dynamic colors change depending on the system's light/dark mode. I am testing the accent color because the app has the ability to set it to whatever the user wants, and that accent color is used as a background for some text. So not every time a light or dark color is clear, I always need to test it when the user changes the accent color to make the text on front of it clear.

Comment: Just to be sure, you don't want to detect whether the user has set Dark Mode or Light Mode in the OS, correct?  If so, there is a [more direct way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57943591/3791245) to check that (and this seems to have been answered on SO before).  If not, and you want this to be a more general dark/light check to reuse elsewhere, carry on.

Comment: @SeanSkelly Yub, it's completely independent of the system's light/dark mode.

Comment: @FarouK Are you sure the accent color changes? IMO it is fixed regardless of the light/dark mode. Btw `Color.accentColor` is get only. How do you change the accentColor?

Comment: @LeoDabus No it's not read only, you can change it using .accentColor() in the view hierarchy. I already have implemented a theme manager to change it and it's working fine :)

Comment: So you are not getting the right color otherwise it wouldn't return the same result

Comment: @LeoDabus No, the color is right and it's changing the background color already, I have add some pictures to the question to see it in action, that blue and purple color are coming from accentColor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the colors in your pictures:

[image]
[image]

And I got exactly the expected answers:

```
isDarkBackground(color:Color(.sRGB, red: 0.346, green: 0.339, blue: 0.836, opacity: 1))
isDarkBackground(color:Color(.sRGB, red: 0.350, green: 0.784, blue: 0.987, opacity: 1))

// 0.37637156163454055, true
// 0.7063881726026535, false
```

So perhaps the input color in your real code is not the color you think it is.

Also there might be some issue with your understanding of what luminance is. I tried your `isDarkBackground` with `Color.blue` and I got your `0.41437413557767866` (which is `true`). But now try it with `Color.yellow`; you get `0.7847599958539009` (which is `false`).

So your code is working perfectly — for what it is. Perhaps the formula you are using is not the formula you really wanted, but the formula itself is behaving correctly.

Comment: In all probability this should be closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color

Comment: Thank you, the problem was in SwiftUI, it's not giving the right color.