# Codenameone: Adapting the app when iOS dark mode is activated

Tags: codenameone

Does anybody know if there is a way in an CN1-App to find out, if the iOS dark mode is activated?

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time. It's something we'd like to add in the future possibly as a cn1lib. You can probably implement this yourself using a native interface e.g. by using something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59431185/756809

Comment: Ok - thanks. I will try to implement an native interface.