# How to check the Toggle is ON for XCUI TEST

Tags: ios, swift, automation, xcuitest

To check the Dark Appearance Toggle is ON for XCUI TEST, can anyone please rectify me as in below code , the flow is not coming inside the if loop, i am using below code.
Code is Below -

```
    if !settings.switches["Dark Appearance"].isEnabled
    {
        settings.switches["Dark Appearance"].tap()
    }
```

Please find attached Screenshot .
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check whether dark mode is enabled in iOS/iPadOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435720/how-can-i-check-whether-dark-mode-is-enabled-in-ios-ipados)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , however the logic i am looking for the if loop , just to check whether the dark mode toggle is on or  not , and if not , then I just want to click m Which i know how to click , so just looking for if loop syntax

Answer (score 1):

Finally worked, so can be closed

```
 if UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .light
 {
    settings.switches["Dark Appearance"].tap()
 }
```