# How to drag label and drop on a box in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uitouch, touchesmoved

I have a couple of labels  and boxes in a view and i want to drag and drop labels on the boxes but the some of labels become hide under the boxes why this happen. I make a subview `gameLayer` and apply touches methods on this view. Here is code

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

    // Create UILabel for Column
    _lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
    _lbl.tag = 100+i;
    _lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    _lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
    [self.gameLayer addSubview:_lbl];
     _lbl.text=[MainArrayFirst objectAtIndex:i];
    [_lbl sizeToFit];

    // Create UILabel Box for ColumnB
    box = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
    box.tag = 300+i;
    box.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    box.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    [self.gameLayer addSubview:box];



  //touches

   -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
      CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.gameLayer];
      _xOffset = pt.x - self.gameLayer.center.x;
      _yOffset = pt.y - self.gameLayer.center.y;

       }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

       UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
       CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.gameLayer];

if (touch.view != self.gameLayer)
    [touch view].center = currentPoint;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let go throught the iteration when your for loop called

i == 0
 label1 add
 box1 add

i == 1
 label2 add
 box2 add

now when you try to drag label1 on Box2 it will be below the box because it add after it so its z order is grater than label1

so for solve your problem you can set your label z order

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

    // Create UILabel for Column
    _lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
    _lbl.tag = 100+i;
    _lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    _lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
    [self.gameLayer addSubview:_lbl];
     _lbl.text=[MainArrayFirst objectAtIndex:i];
    _lbl.layer.zPosition = 2;
    [_lbl sizeToFit];

    // Create UILabel Box for ColumnB
    box = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
    box.tag = 300+i;
    box.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    box.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    box.layer.zPosition = 1;
    [self.gameLayer addSubview:box];
}
```

also there are many ways to do this stuff you can refers this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631878/how-to-set-iphone-ui-view-z-index)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your storyboard select the viewController and try changing the order of the label and "boxes" on 'Document Outline'(The list shown on the left of   storyboard window). This might bring up your label to the front.

Comment: I,m not using storyboards as labels and boxes are created programmatically ,my reputation is low otherwise i will down vote you as it is not a proper answer....