# I searched hard but can't find a way to change controllers order

Tags: ios, cocoa

in swift I'd like to programatically re-arranger the order
of my control

by example I have a textview that is on top of another one
and I'd like to change their orders in which they appear (send to back)ect

I looked hard online but can't find an answer to this

update:

I read the article linked but those solutions don't work in swift 4.0

Comment: Question not clear. Pls explain your requirement more clearly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set iPhone UIView z index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631878/how-to-set-iphone-uiview-z-index)

Comment: At daiydiumboy, you know how u can change their visible order in Xcode via the menu under view controler scene they appear in that order that they are in on that list so if the textfield is over a scroll view we will see the textfield and  the scrollview will be hidden I want to this programaticly

Answer (score 0):

You have following methods to manipulate which subview is above/behind other:

```
bringSubviewToFront(_:)
sendSubviewToBack(_:)
removeFromSuperview()
insertSubview(_:atIndex:)
insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)
insertSubview(_:belowSubview:)
exchangeSubviewAtIndex(_:withSubviewAtIndex:)
```

If you need to know current index(z position) of subview, it corresponds to its index in superview.subviews array.