# Background view is over the rest of the UI

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I tested the app on my iPhone, but I thought that all the objects were deleted because only the background was showing up.
When I checked if the rest still was there, I found out that the background was over the rest of the images and labels in a higher layer.
How can I place the background in the lowest layer so the rest of the objects are on top of the background?

[image: screenshot of Interface Builder]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set iPhone UIView z index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631878/how-to-set-iphone-uiview-z-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [send(toBack: UIView)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622618-sendsubview) function of UIView to send the UIImageView subview to the back of the view hierarchy or you can adjust the [zPosition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition) of the image view's layer so send it to the back.

If your using interface builder, you can drag the background image view to the top of the list in the Document outline window.

Otherwise if you prefer to do it via code you can do something like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     self.view.send(toBack: backgroundImageView)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved.
I really appreciate you help.