# How can i find the superview/parentviewcontroller of a view inside a stackview

Tags: ios, swift, subview, stackview, superview

Hopefully this isn't too confusing.

I have a main view controller (`MainView`) with a stackview at the bottom of the view and inside the stackview I have three views. Inside one the views (lets call it `footerView`) i'm adding a little `tooltipView` - and because footerView is nestled inside a stackview at the bottom of `MainView` - it's got some overlap with the other views. I want to tell the `tooltipView` to be on top of all the views but it's not working. Inside `footerView` - it has no `superview` (I presume because it's inside a stackview) so I can't use `parentView.bringSubviewToFront(childView)`.

What could I do instead? Is delegation through the layers the only way?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set the `zPosition` of each layer. The default value is 0 so you may not get the desired value you want without manually controlling it. As an example you could try

> tooltipView.layer.zPosition = 1

or

> tooltipView.layer.zPosition = .greatestFiniteMagnitude

Setting it to 1 will make it above other views that default to 0 or setting it to `.greatestFiniteMagnitude` will always have it at the front.

Check out [this answer on zPostion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631878/how-to-set-iphone-uiview-z-index/9311536) and [Apple's documentation on zPostion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition).

Answer (score 0):

Tommy's answer did help but another thing that helped was that I was creating my `tooltipView` before `footerView` had finished being set up - hence why the `superview` was `nil`. I moved the initialisation of `tooltipView` to be inside `func layoutSubviews()` and it works.

But ALSO make sure you untick `clip to bounds`. This is why no matter what i did with `zPosition` made no difference